# SQL QUERY - Filter date from the beginning

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write SQL query that will sum the amount from the previous days/years. Like from the start.

Scenario I want to compute accumulated sales of the store from the day it was opened.

Example

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM TransactionTable 
WHERE TransactionDate = ???
```

The plan that I have is to query on this table and get the oldest transaction date record, then I will use that in the `WHERE` condition. Do you think that it is the best solution?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the result you expected. And witch version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below using `having min(transaction)` which will give you the date when transaction first started

```
select sum (amt) from
(
  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) as amt from TransactionTable 
  group by TransactionDate 
  having TransactionDate between min(TransactionDate) and getdate()
)A
```

Answer (score 2):

To compute accumulated sales of the store from the day it started you can use `SUM` with `OVER` clause

```
SELECT TransactionDate, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS AccumulatedSales
FROM TransactionTable
```

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` TransactionDate

```
SELECT convert(date,TransactionDate), SUM(AMOUNT) from TransactionTable 
group by  convert(date,TransactionDate)
```